# Replace string between two items

Tags: javascript, regex

Fairly simple question, how can I replace `\n` with `{br}` between two `<blockquote>` and `</blockquote>` tags?

thought this would work, but it doesn't:

```
val = val.replace(/<blockquote>\b\n\b<\/blockquote>/igm, "{br}");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a replacement callback:

```
val = val.replace(
    /<blockquote>[\s\S]*?<\/blockquote>/i,
    function(m) {return m.replace(/\n/g,"{br}");}
);
```

Comment: Swapped it out for a match-all class.